# Fastest rocket to reach space?

Tags: launch, record, acceleration, karman-line

[Spaceloft XL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceLoft_XL) can reach space - 100 km - in 60 seconds

So I wonder which rockets can reach that limit fastest

Balloon-launched sounding rockets count but separately (from the moment they launch from the baloon)

Rockets launched from a winged vehicle count too.

Comment: Do balloon-launched sounding rockets count?

Comment: Yes they do count

Comment: Does the time start when the balloon launches or when the rocket lights off from the balloon?

Comment: from the moment they launch from the baloon

Comment: does a rocket launched from a winged vehicle count?

Comment: Yes they also count

Answer (score 2):

I believe the winner in this department is going to be the Sprint missile.  While it was not intended to go into space it would be heading up at more than Mach 10, it would reach space if nothing happened to it first.  Since it was designed to reach 30km I would think most of them wouldn't burn through the remaining ablator (yes, it had a heat shield for going **up**) with what little is left of the atmosphere at that point.

Comment: I thought of that one too, but I could not confirm that one ever reached space.

Comment: How quick they can reach 30 km?

Comment: @JoeJobs The flight time was expected to not exceed 15 seconds--that's not only going up but going sideways also.